# App crashes when Launching "Unfortunately, has stopped"

Tags: android

I have a program and when I try to start it, it crashes. I really don't understand why, even Eclipse show's that there are no errors.
I can show you the code of a page on which I think is the problem.

```
 package ctect.android.maxipro;

 import android.os.Bundle; 
 import android.app.Activity; 
 import android.content.Intent; 
 import android.view.Menu; 
 import android.view.View; 
 import android.widget.Button;

 public class BasicScreenActivity extends Activity  { 
     private Button butonul1; 
     private Button butonul2;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic_screen);

         butonul1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override           
            public void onClick(View currentView) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub        
              butonul2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override           
                public void onClick(View currentView) {
                          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(currentView.getContext(), NeedForSpeedActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                        Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(currentView.getContext(), Fifa2012Activity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent2, 0); 
                    }   
                });             
            }       
         });
     }


     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.basic_screen, menu);
         return true;
     }
 }
```

if somebody understands, please help me.

Comment: `even Eclipse show's that there are no errors`  Excuse me for being direct and honest, but can you really not understand why Eclipse cannot show you errors that only happen at runtime?  It is impossible to get runtime errors until you have resolved all of the compile time errors since you cannot even run your app until it compiles.  if Eclipse showed runtime errors, then every app would be error free!  So that people can find your error, please post the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: Did you consider making the code in your question readable before asking for help. Also pls post log from `logcat`.

Comment: **even Eclipse show's that there are no errors** - but there's a reason why it's called "Eclipse" not "oracle".

Comment: Hahah.. This is just becoming a troll for the reason that the OP seems to be unaware of what a `RuntimeException` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to assign an object to `butonul1` before using it. You need to add this line before `butonul1.setOnClickListener`:

`butonul1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.butonul1);`

This is assuming that you gave it the id `butonul1` in your layout file.

Comment: Just make sure you put it after `setContentView` or it will still crash